# Why has NHibernate 3.3.3.4001 assembly version 3.3.1?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to resolve some assembly binding redirects for NHibernate 3.1 to 3.3.3.4001.  I've not been having much luck with the following:

```
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate"
                              publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.3.4001"
                             newVersion="3.3.3.40001" />
        </dependentAssembly>
```

The DLL properties indicate the file version is 3.3.3.4001, however DotPeek says that the FQ AssemblyName is "NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4".

What's going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [dll versions displayed in visual studio .Net not reflecting the referenced dll file/product versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576604/dll-versions-displayed-in-visual-studio-net-not-reflecting-the-referenced-dll-f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this NHibernate-Development group [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/nhibernate-development/BQiu5eEIbRc).

> NHibernate 3.3.3.SP1 keeps the previous assembly version so it's a
>   drop in replacement for 3.3.1 - 3.3.3.

I am not sure why this is the case, maybe something todo with NuGet etc, Did you try using `newVersion="3.3.1.4000"`

Comment: Yup - did that in the end and it worked.  Just took a DotPeek decmpile for me to figure out the correct version and that was not obvious...